# Hide a HTML Label in the CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

We have a a interactive filter on our company website, used to show people based on department, without wanting to spend more money on a developer who has access to the templates, we can make CSS changes via wordpress.

Can hide the filters themselves at the moment as they seem to be contained within a style called : #Filters_Department

Label appears like this but other labels on the page we don't want to hide.

```
<label>Department:</label>
```

This Works for part of it.

```
#filters_department
{
display:none    
}
```

Have tried:

```
label[for="department"]
{
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just have to add the for attribute to your label.

```
<label for="department">Department : </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try adding a class to the label and targeting it that way?

```
<label class="hidden">Hidden label</label>

.hidden { display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This selector works with attributes

- [attribute="value"] - looks for attribute that is matching exactly with the "value"
- [attribute^="value"] - looks for attribute that starts with the "value"
- [attribute*="value"] - looks for attribute that includes "value" somewhere in it

  In your case you don't have any attributes. Add
  class="..." or id="..." or custom data-attr="..."

If you use class or id attributes, better use the .value {} or #value {} selector.

But note that these selectors have different importance than the attribute selectors, it is good to know when overwriting.

See the example below

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

label[data-attr="dept-1"] {
  display: none;
}

label[class="someClass"] {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.someClass {
  color: red;
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* class selector can't overwrite the attribute selector */

#someId {
  color: red;
}

/* id selector can overwrite the attribute and the class selector*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CSS</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <label class="someClass" data-attr="dept-1">Department: 1</label>
  <label class="someClass" data-attr="dept-2">Department: 2</label>
  <label class="someClass" data-attr="dept-3" id="someId" >Department: 3</label>
</body>

</html>
```